# Create XML tree with attribute using Linq to XML

Tags: c#

I would like to create a XML with attributes using LINQ to XML.
eg:

```
<class name="Pessoa" tabela="pessoa">
    <property name="id" column="id" pk="true"/>
    <property name="nome" column="nome"/>
    <property name="genero" column="genero"/>
    <property name="dataNasc" column="data_nasc" type="date"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a answer [here](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/linq-to-xml-vs-xml-dom-xmldom-and-linq-to-xml-with-lambda-expression.aspx):

```
XElement n = new XElement("class",
                new XElement("property",
                    new XAttribute("name", "id"),
                    new XAttribute("column", "id")),

                    new XElement("property",

                        new XAttribute("name", "dataNasc"),
                        new XAttribute("column", "data_nasc"),
                        new XAttribute("pk", "true")));
```